# Aurelia, converter use inside view model

Tags: javascript, viewmodel, aurelia, converters

Using Aurelia, i'm trying to use a converter inside a view model. But I don't know how to do it or if it's even possible.

**With AngularJS, for example :**
*inside a view*

```html
<span>{{ 'hello' | uppercase }}</span>
```

*inside a controller*

```js
$filter('uppercase')('hello');
```

**With Aurelia**
*inside a view*

```html
<span>${ 'hello' | uppercase }</span>
```

*inside a viewmodel*

```js
?????????
```

Comment: you could inject the converter in your viewmodel and call its toView() method?
That being said, apart from a very simple use-case, I would rather write a getter property in the viewmodel and ditch the converter altogether, or write the converter logic in a service and call the service from your converter and viewModel, depending on the complexity and the number of times used within your app

Comment: this is the answer I expected, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so, this is simple.
As our converters are classes, we just have to call the method toView from an instance.

```js
import { UppercaseValueConverter } from './converters';

const convertedValue = new UppercaseValueConverter().toView('Hello');
```

In my case I was a little bit lost, because I use a library and can't import the converter class directly.

Answer (score -1):

In your viewmodel add the following code:

```js
export class UppercaseValueConverter {
  toView(value) {
    return value?.toUpperCase();
  }
}
```

and then in your view:

```html
<h1>${message | uppercase}</h1>
```

See a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-yalow-ls7h8?file=/src/app.html).

You can also add the value converter to the global resources section of your app to share it among all views.

Comment: I didn't talk about converter viewmodel ; but others viewmodel. I expect an equivalent of what i wrote in angularjs.

Comment: In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122849/how-to-evaluate-an-aurelia-interpolation-expression-outside-a-view there is a converter used directly in a binding expression in a view-model.